# I am not sure how to use the secant method formula without a function being given?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Calculate an approximation value for $4^{\frac34}$ using four steps of the secant method with the starting values of $x_0=3$ and $x_1=2$.

Comment: $x = 4^{3/4}$ means $x^4 = 4^3$, so how about taking $x^4-64$?

Answer (score 3):

You need to construct a function $f(x)$ such that $f(4^{\frac 34})=0$.  There are many of those.  One simple one is $f(x)=x- 4^{\frac 34}$.  As Daniel Fischer suggests, another is $f(x)=x^4-64$.  These will suggest others.  The important thing is that the root be where you want and that the function be smooth and not have local maxima/minima in the region of interest.  They may make your iteration not behave properly.